# android json parsing "<br cannot be converted to json"

Tags: android, json, android-volley

This is the JSON    `{"result":[{"emailfrom":"s@s.com"}]}`

That i want to parse. I am trying to parse it in the below manner:

```
  final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.YO_URL,
                    new Response.Listener<String >() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);

                                JSONObject json_LL = json.getJSONObject("result");

                                String str_value=json_LL.getString("emailfrom");
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,str_value,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                              }
                              catch(JSONException e)
                              {
                               print.stactTrace(e);
                               }
                       }
                     }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        //You can handle error here if you want

                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }){

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                //Adding parameters to request
                params.put("emailto", email);
                //returning parameter
                return params;
            }
        };
        //Adding the string request to the queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }
```

But when i try this i get an error saying org.json.JSONException: Value

How to i parse this json? 
Please help me out guys!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. I didn't test it but it will solve your problem.

```
   try { 
           JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response); 
           JSONArray json_LL = json.getJSONArray("result"); 
           for(int i=0;i<json_LL.length();i++){
               JSONObject jsonObj= json_LL.get(i);
               String str_value=jsonObj.getString("emailfrom");
            } 
         } 
    catch(JSONException e){ 
           print.stactTrace(e); 
         }
```

Comment: Bharat Ghimire Thank you so much, it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

result is an array, so your code should be
`JSONArray json_LL = json.getJSONArray("result");`
and then you will get the first object in the array...

Comment: Hey Thank you for the response, but the same error exists still :(